# 2-norm of upper non-singular $n \times n$ submatrix as an upper bound of the 2-norm of the entire $m\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-equations, svd

Suppose
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_1\\A_2\end{bmatrix}$$
where $A_1\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is non-singular and $A_2\in \mathbb{C}^{(m-n)\times n}$ is arbitrary.

Prove $\left\Vert A^+\right\Vert_2 \leq \left\Vert A_1^{-1}\right\Vert_2$, where $A^+ = (A^*A)^{-1}A^*$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$.

(out of Trefethen and Bau's "Numerical Linear Algebra")

A bit of help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a QR factorization of $A$ in the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_1\\A_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1\\Q_2
\end{bmatrix}
R=:QR
$$
where $Q$ has orthogonal columns and is partitioned in the same way as $A$. The matrix $A$ has full column rank so $R$ is nonsingular.

We have $A^+=R^{-1}Q^*$ and hence $\|A^+\|_2=\|R^{-1}\|_2$. We have to show that $\|R^{-1}\|_2\leq\|A_1^{-1}\|_2$. From $A_1=Q_1R$, we get $R^{-1}=A_1^{-1}Q_1$ and 
$$
\|R^{-1}\|_2\leq\|Q_1\|_2\|A_1^{-1}\|_2.
$$
But $Q_1$ is a submatrix of $Q$ so $\|Q_1\|_2\leq\|Q\|_2=1$.